# How to escape built in function in Less?

Tags: css, less

I have the following

```
.linear-gradient(~"to left, #83111b 0, #83111b 50%, lighten(#83111b, 5%) 50%, lighten(#83111b, 5%) 100%");
```

`linear-gradient` is as follows

```
.linear-gradient(@params) {
    background-image: linear-gradient(@params);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(@params);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(@params);
}
```

Is it possible to escape the `lighten(#83111b, 5%)` ?
I understand I can use a variable to store it but I like to avoid that part.

Comment: I don't think you can do it that way because the entire thing becomes a single string. You may need to get the function's value into a variable and then use it within the mixin's param (like this - `@color1: lighten(#83111b, 5%); .linear-gradient(~"to left, #83111b 0, #83111b 50%, @{color1} 50%, @{color1} 100%");`)

Comment: Yep, annoyingly you can't do things like `"something @{lighten(#000, 20%)}"` you can only interpolate variables like `"something @{varName}"`

Comment: I see, can one of you leave an answer in case other people have the same question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot call a built-in function within an escaped string because then it gets treated as a single string and so the function wouldn't get called/evaluated.

Surprisingly, it seems like a temporary variable is not required and something like the below works for this particular case. Less compiler seems to be concatenating and treating the entire thing as a single parameter.

```
.linear-gradient(@params) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(@params);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(@params);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(@params);
}
a{
  .linear-gradient(~"to left, #83111b 0, #83111b 50%," lighten(#83111b, 5%) ~"50%," lighten(#83111b, 5%) ~"100%");
}
```

This model seems to be working fine for a lot of similar cases and so I think it would not be invalidated. In fact, since they are space separated (and not comma separated),the extra semi-colon at the end is also not required. (*A semi-colon is required only when comma separated values should be considered as a single parameter. This is because either semicolon or comma can be used as a mixin parameter separator but when semicolon is present the comma is no longer considered as the separator.)*

---

But I would still recommend doing something like the below because it looks more readable and clear.

```
.linear-gradient(@params) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(@params);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(@params);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(@params);
}

a{
  @color1: lighten(#83111b, 5%);
  .linear-gradient(~"to left, #83111b 0, #83111b 50%, @{color1} 50%, @{color1} 100%");
}
```

The option suggested by Qwertiy is also a very good one but be careful with the `@arguments` option because when there are multiple other parameters for the same mixin, it would concatenate all into one single space separated value.

Comment: (Not counting the usual "wake up and use autoprefixer bla-bla-bla"), technically, no escaping is necessary in this case. [example](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.linear-gradient(%40params...)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20background-image%3A%20linear-gradient(%40params)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cna%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%40color1%3A%20lighten(%2383111b%2C%205%25)%3B%5Cn%20%20.linear-gradient(to%20left%2C%20%2383111b%200%2C%20%2383111b%2050%25%2C%20%40color1%2050%25%2C%20%40color1%20100%25%3B)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%7D).

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to escape the `lighten(#83111b, 5%)`?

No. If you want to pass the string with commas, use `@arguments` and add a semicolon before closing bracket on the caller side.

> ```
> .linear-gradient(~"to left, #83111b 0, #83111b 50%, lighten(#83111b, 5%) 50%, lighten(#83111b, 5%) 100%");
> ```

> ```
> .linear-gradient(@params) {
>     background-image: linear-gradient(@params);
>     background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(@params);
>     background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(@params);
> }
> ```

Wrong. While `linear-gradient` has `to left` the other two should have `right` instead of it.

Also it's good to place prefixed variants before the standard one.

Comment: Yea i have changed the left/right thing and rearranged the rules